# How do I get rid of annoying nonlethal errors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio

I know the code works even with the nonlethal errors (yellow squiggly), but it would be great if there was a way to get rid of them

```py
def generate_map():
#this function makes the map for the current room
#using room data, scenery data, and prop data
    global room_map, room_width, room_height, room_name, hazard_map
    global top_left_x, top_left_y, wall_transparency_Frame
    room_data = GAME_MAP[current_room]
    room_height = room_data[1]
    room_width = room_data[2]

    floor_type = get_floor_type()
    if current_room in range(1, 21):
        bottom_edge = 2 #soil
        side_edge = 2 #soil
    if current_room in range(21, 26):
        bottom_edge = 1 #wall
        side_edge = 2 #soil
    if current_room > 25:
        bottom_edge = 1 #wall
        side_edge = 1 #wall

    # Create top line of room map.
    room_map=[[side_edge] * room_width]
    # Add middle lines of room map (wall, floor to fill width, wall).
    for y in range(room_height - 2):
        room_map.append([side_edge]
            + [floor_type]*(room_width - 2) + [side_edge])
```

[the program I'm using says that] the instances of side_edge and floor_type are the (nonlethal) errors
(sorry if I did something wrong in this post)

Comment: What do you mean by a non-lethal error.  Is this an error presented by the IDE you are using?

Comment: Try hovering over the errors in your IDE to find what is causing them. It looks like they are most likely formatting specifics.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Create top line of room map.
room_map=[[**side_edge**] * room_width]
# Add middle lines of room map (wall, floor to fill width, wall).
for y in range(room_height - 2):
    room_map.append([**side_edge**]
        + [**floor_type**]*(room_width - 2) + [**side_edge**])
```

You can't use power operator in list indexing `[**side_edge**]` is invalid syntax.

Comment: I think the `**` was an attempt to make the text bold.  Doesn't work in a code block though.

Comment: I was trying to bold it, but I didn't know that it doesn't work in block text